# artist working with base 64

Tags: base64

Hi Im fairly new to base64 code and could do with some info/help etc. I have recently used it while converting my photos into code as part of an experiment regarding my sculptures, I converted a photo into 152 pages of base 64 using an online converter, just to get started. I was wondering how I can reverse this, and also if I edited out some code would the image change or would it not convert at all!? Like I said I am interested in using this to help my experiments. thanks for any info .

Comment: do you need to use base64 at all? base64 is really only useful if you are trying to transfer raw binary over communication links that only support ASCII

Comment: It was a first attempt at converting my image to code, I want to use the code instead of an actual image of my work, I find it really interesting. what alternatives are there? ive heard of various base codes and ASCII, i like the idea that someone could convert what I show into an image. thanks

Comment: An alternative that you might also find interesting is that you can convert your image file into 'ASCII Art', there are a few free generators out there.  However, you won't be able to decode back into the original picture.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, I have had a go at ASCII Art, but its not really what I am after. Really like the idea that a single image can be converted into a mass of information/code, then recoded back into the image by anyone. Guess I like the process of it as well, I have tried taking some lines of code out, which looks interesting but occasionally, it wont convert, Anyone know how to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 decode functions will decode it. If you remove some of the base64 code it may not translate back into a valid image or translate into valid base64 code at all depending on how much you remove. Depending on how the image was originally compressed, it MAY give you something, but the results will be incredibly unpredictable... So you'll never know what the result of the change will be on the final product. Part of the base64 standard involves a padded width (which is why some strings end in up to 2 = signs).

Comment: ahhh right OK, thanks a lot for that. I will try a few decoding s and see what happens. just out of interest, as Im new to coding are there programs I can get to decode for me, I'm not up to scratch with decoding myself? thanks

Comment: Most of the popular languages, if not all, should have a library capable of encoding or decoding base 64. Really what I think you're looking for is a program that will pipe the output of a file that contains base64 into another file that you can then attempt to open with an image editor. I know most Linux distributions come with a program that can do just that called base64.

Comment: hi, I am still working with base64, I just wondered if there is a set width for a base64 code. I have tried converting an image into base 64, and they come back roughly the same width, by this I mean when I copy it to word it doesnt copy and fill the width of the page!